# Multi Array merge into new array with key

Tags: php, arrays

Original Array:

```
$cat = Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [id] => 2 [name] => W [pid] => 1 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [id] => 4 [name] => M [pid] => 1 ) 
    [2] => Array ( [id] => 5 [name] => C [pid] => 1 ) 
    [3] => Array ( [id] => 8 [name] => K [pid] => 7 ) 
    [4] => Array ( [id] => 9 [name] => B [pid] => 7 ) 
    [5] => Array ( [id] => 12 [name] => X [pid] => 11 )
)
```

I want to get this results:

```
$cat = Array ( 
    [0] => Array (
        [pid]=>1,
        [item] => Array(
            [0] => Array ( [id] => 2 [name] => W ),
            [1] => Array ( [id] => 4 [name] => M ),
            [2] => Array ( [id] => 5 [name] => C )
        )
    ),
    [1] => Array (
        [pid]=>7,
        [item]=>Array(
            [0] => Array ( [id] => 8 [name] => K ),
            [0] => Array ( [id] => 9 [name] => B )
        )
    ),
    [2] => Array (
        [pid]=>11,
        [item]=>Array(
            [0] => Array ( [id] => 12 [name] => X )
        )
    )
)
```

How?

Comment: So, you want to merge all the items with the same `pid`?  Have you tried anything yet?  We love helping here, but you need to show what you've tried.  Where are you stuck?  What part do you need help with?  We're not going to just do it for you.

Comment: @meda: just paste in the link. SO will linkify it for you.

Comment: Please read up on [`merge_array`](http://us1.php.net/array_merge)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
$newCat = array();
array_walk($cat, function($v) use(&$newCat){
    $i = $v['pid']; 
    unset($v['pid']);
    if(!isset($newCat[$i]))
        $newCat[$i] = array('pid' => $i, 'item' => array());
    $newCat[$i]['item'][] = $v;
});

print_r( array_values($newCat) );
```

[**demo**](http://ideone.com/FIiFtR)